# Read from multiple csv files in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

How can I read from multiple CSV files with thousands and thousands of lines of data and calculate data separately for each file and print it out in one csv file. Is that possible?

For example:

1. 200 csv files with each files containing 5000+ lines of data
2. For each csv file I would like to use some conditions and do the
   calculations based on that
3. At the end I would like one csv file which has the calculations of all 200 csv files listed separately.

Example of 2 CSV file

example.csv

```
Fname      Lname     ID    Online(Y/N)   URL           Address
John       Doe       123   Y             xyz.com       NJ
Jane       Doe       234   N             abc.com       CA
Jane       Doe       234   Y             abc.com       CA
```

ex.csv

```
Fname      Lname     ID    Online(Y/N)   URL           Address
John       Doe       123   Y             xyz.com       NJ
Jane       Doe       234   N             abc.com       CA
Jane       Doe       234   Y             abc.com       CA 
Jane       Doe       234   Y             abc.com       CA
```

Conditions to use for calculations:

- Read from all the csv files and the input files has "|" to separate values.
- If Online = yes and if URL = abc and if address = CA then count it as A or count it as B
- Print the results in CSV

Output.csv

```
Filename     A    B
example      1    2
ex           2    2
```

What's the best way of doing that?

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTFILE = 'finalcount.csv'

CAT $1 | tr "," " " | tr -d '"' | tr -d "\t" | \  (Is this the best way to remove white space and , and etc from the input file?)

awk -F"|" 'NR>1 {$4=="Y" && $5=="*abc.com" && $6=="CA" ? a++ : b++}

END {print FILENAME,a,b}' *.csv
```

What changes should I make to this code?

Comment: Still using `awk`, like Glenn told you last time... http://stackoverflow.com/q/34470691/2836621

Comment: If you can do whatever it is you're trying to do with 3 csv files, each with 5 lines of  data, then I'm sure you'll be able to do it for 200 csv files each with 5000+ lines of data. So, please, show us 3 csv files each with 5 lines of data along with the desired output and a brief explanation of how to create it. Ideally it would be great to show an attempt that you've made yourself, but even without that, just by putting some example input with the desired output I bet you'll have an answer in hardly any time at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided any code I'll give a solution for a single file, perhaps you can work on it for multiple input files

```
$ awk 'NR>1 { $4=="Y" && $5=="abc.com" && $6=="CA" ? a++ : b++ } 
         END{print FILENAME, a, b}' ex.csv

ex.csv 2 2
```

for actual csv input you need to set file separator to comma with `-F,` option. Skipping first header lines can be done with `FNR` (hint you can use it for detecting input file changes as well)

Comment: What changes should I make to this code?            
OUTFILE = 'finalcount.csv'

CAT $1 | tr "," " " | tr -d '"' | tr -d "\t" | \ (Is this the best way to remove white space and , and etc from the input file?)

awk -F"|" 'NR>1 {$4=="Y" && $5=="*abc.com" && $6=="CA" ? a++ : b++}

END {print FILENAME,a,b}' *.csv